# how to fix all the directory errors when adding a program under a new directory?

Tags: python, oop, subdirectory

I'm pretty new to programming and I wanted to learn how to utilize programs outside my own: my focus was to design a web interface for this program: https://github.com/teplinsky-maxim/spotify-playlist-downloader.git.

I cloned the program into my project but it was not able to find the "core" directory in main.py file during run-time. VS Code also said it was unable to find the definition of the directory, although its able to find the definition of the class its importing (which is weird).

*The program is able to run outside the project*

import statements:

```
import argparse
import asyncio
import time

from core.downloader.soundloader.soundloader import SoundLoaderDownloader
from core.logger.main import Logger
from core.playlist.extractor.spotify.spotify import PlaylistExtractor
```

Error:

```
...
  File "C:\Users\ppwan\My shit\Giraffe\spotifyv4\giraffe\spotify-playlist-downloader\core\downloader\soundloader\soundloader.py", line 13, in <module>
    from core.downloader.base import DownloaderBase
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'
```

-> First thing I did was to implement an **innit**.py file within the core directory. Didn't work.

-> The program installed had hyphens in the name, cloned it with and replaced hyphens with underscores. Had a lot of issues, too scared to change anything. (tentative)

-> tried to convert with absolute path, but again python didn't like the hyphens. Didn't work.

-> used importlib, but all of the files, even the ones in core directory, needed their import statements changed. would take too long.

Whats the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following lines to your program:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())
```

This will insert your working directory to `Path`.

Comment: The problem still persists even after adding it.

Comment: Did you add it at the **top** of the main code?